# "dyld: Library not loaded", "libruby.1.9.1.dylib" when calling "mvim ." in the command line

Tags: ruby, shell, vim, rvm, macvim

I'm trying to open my rails project into mvim (macvim) using "mvim ." but I get the following error.

```
➜  cs193p git:(master) mvim .
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
  Reason: image not found
[1]    85219 trace trap  mvim .
➜  cs193p git:(master) mvim --version
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
  Reason: image not found
```

I recently removed RVM ("rvm implode" which included ruby 1.9.3-p125) and reinstalled 1.9.3-p194. What do I need to do to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: solved. not sure this is the correct way to do it but i installed 1.9.3-p125. 1.9.3-p194 is still my default though.

Comment: just answer your own question and click it as the right answer :)

Comment: You probably need to rebuild macvim against 1.9.3-p194.  How did you install macvim in the first place?

Comment: @RandyMorris to install macvim i believe i used homebrew. do i need to rebuild macvim to ruby 1.9.3-p194? if so, how do i do it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to force it to rebuild, you may just have to `brew remove macvim` and then `brew install macvim` with the newer ruby installed.

Comment: FYI: I was getting a similar error in MacVim as installed by MacPorts. Reinstalling should work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

brew will compile MacVim against your currently active ruby which was probably 1.9.3-p125. `rvm use 1.9.3-p194 --default && brew uninstall macvim && brew install macvim` is probably your best bet to fix your problem.

Comment: I just did that, and it still doesn't work. Please note that I have only one ruby installed.