# Library not loaded error -- wrong ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm using RVM with Ruby 1.9.3 p448, but when I try to run my rails server, I get this error (plus some other stuff)

```
9): Library not loaded: /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib (LoadError)
      Referenced from: /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle
```

The weird thing is, it's referencing ruby-1.9.3-p327, which isn't even one of my RVM installs. Should I delete that Ruby folder it's not finding libruby in? Or what else might be wrong?

**EDIT -- Full Error**

```
/Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': dlopen(/Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix-spawn.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/albino-1.3.3/lib/albino.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
  from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
  from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  from /Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The albino gem seems to be at the bottom of this, but I think it's necessary for the app, so I can't just take it out. I tried gem uninstall albino (which gave no output) and then bundle install, but that didn't fix anything. Likewise with bundle update, and likewise with mpapis's and sahil's help below.

Comment: does this old question help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287274/dyld-library-not-loaded-libruby-1-9-1-dylib-when-calling-mvim-in-the-c

Comment: and i hope you did `rvm use ruby_version_you_want_to_use --default` before starting your rails server.

Comment: Hmm. I tried installing p327, like the original poster, and that didn't work. Then I tried reinstalling my bundle. Then I commented out the offending gem, and that didn't work. RVM is using the correct ruby by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this kind of thing could happen when gems are linked wrong, try this:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p448
rvm use 1.9.3-p448
```

This will reinstall the ruby and make all gems pristine, which should prevent such problems from happening - unless gem authors did some extra tricks which go out of standard ruby detection.

## Update

Using `bundler`s flag `--deployment` or `--path` is not always safe, the error message says:

```
/Users/sashafklein/rails/<appname>/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle
```

Which means the gem was compiled with the other ruby and now can not find it.

The simplest way to fix it is to stop using `--deployment`  flag, as it is persisted the easiest way to get rid of it (and all other potentially dangerous settings) is:

```
rm -rf .bundle/ vendor/bundle 
bundle install
```

### Interpretation

Bundler does great job filtering gems in runtime, unfortunately it enforces another layer of filtering with the `--deployment` flag, which forces installation of gems to path that is common for multiple rubies - in this case: `ruby/1.9.1`, this is unsafe as rubies can be compiled with different settings which can break c-extension gems used in different ruby.

Comment: Thanks! But alas, the issue persists. I think it's a problem with the gem -- which seems to be specifically requiring p327, for whatever reason. Though this works on my other computer. Can't remember what ruby version it's using. At any rate, I'll post the full error above. Maybe there's something in there that hasn't been obvious.

Comment: I missed it at first, updated my answer with fix and description