# Unable to find ruby gems when installed with bundle install --path

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am using bundle to install all the needed gems into a local folder for the ease of development and testing

```
 bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

And I can find libs are being installed under the folder "vendor/bundle", but how to tell my ruby to use that folder as well?

e.g. When I start my program in the shell

```
/Users/howard/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': cannot load such file -- yajl (LoadError)
```

But *yajl* is under the folder */vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is too obvious, but just in case... Did you try:

```
bundle exec your_script.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply install the bundle or create a gemset. then try.

Comment: my point is I don't want to mix the gem with the currently system intalled one, I want them under the vendor/bundle. But I need to find a way to load them during my ruby script started.

Comment: have you tried this
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/02/24/how-to-have-bundler-load-a-custom-gem-into-a-rails-3-app/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168341/library-not-loaded-error-wrong-ruby
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573596/what-is-the-purpose-of-vendor-bundle-heroku-tells-me-to-remove-it