# rvm acting up and disabling vim

Tags: rvm

I'm using OSX mavericks. I installed vim using homebrew, which worked fine for several months, but at some point rvm started acting up and throwing cryptic errors whenever I opened a console. I deleted `~/.rvm` and reinstalled it from scratch, which solved the problem, but today when I tried to use vim I got this message:

```
➜  ~  vim
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/yo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/libruby.2.1.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
[1]    75365 trace trap  vim
```

The weirdest thing is that I don't even have ruby 2.1.1 installed. I used to have it installed before deleting `~/.rvm`, but when I reinstalled rvm I upgraded to ruby 2.1.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11316525/607368

Answer (score 0):

`brew reinstall vim` worked for me.